# Silverlight 4: forbid isolated storage removal via clientaccesspolicy.xml

Tags: silverlight, permissions, isolatedstorage, clientaccesspolicy.xml

I am trying to find some information how to organize permissions for silverlight application via clientaccesspolicy.xml.

Main question : how can I affect how isolated storage works via clientaccesspolicy.xml? Can I disable isolated storage or forbid isolated storage deletion via clientaccesspolicy.xml?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `clientaccesspolicy.xml` file controls which clients have access to your server.

It does not have any effect on whether your Silverlight client application can access isolated storage on the user's machine.